# Changing a field type causes the field disappear from the editing form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I tried to change the type of a column of a list from the Elements.xml file. The original type of the field was Note, the new is LookupMulti. But after that the field does not appear on the editing form. 
When I delete the field from the Library settings and then add it to again to the list, like an existing column, it works corretly.

Can anyone help me? What did I wrong? It is good to know this is a sharepoint wiki site, and the page which includes this field based on a content type.

Answer (score 1):

This is by default when you edit the element.xml. We cannot do anything to rectify it.

If you are editing the file in Visual studio & have a list definition & other stuff, then I think it should not be a problem.

But when you try to edit the file in layouts folder, then you have to manually recreate it.
As you might have noticed while using UI to do the same, SP will WARN you about loss of information in that field & does the DELETING/ADDING the column for you

Comment: Please don't use `<br>`, just put a new line.